# JS - Get top 5 max elements from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I get top 5 max elements from array of ints with the standard library of es2015? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A solution in ES6 :

```
values = [1,65,8,98,689,12,33,2,3,789];
var topValues = values.sort((a,b) => b-a).slice(0,5);
console.log(topValues); // [789,689,98,65,33]
```

Many others exist, ask if you need more

Comment: `(a,b) => a>b` - well, not really.

Comment: [2, 6, 8, 1].sort((a, b) => b>a) [2, 6, 8 1] incorrect
[2, 6, 8, 1].sort((a, b) => b - a) [8, 6, 2, 1] correct, the sort function should be `(a,b) => b - a`

Answer (score 5):

[2, 6, 8, 1, 10, 11].sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0,5)

[11, 10, 8, 6, 2]

Answer (score 3):

Although above approach by @Kevin and @Cody is correct, it would also change the original array which might affect your code. I would recommend to copy the array first, and then perform sort. As your array is of ints only, we can shallow copy it. To do so, you can use spread operator :

```
values = [1,65,8,98,689,12,33,2,3,789];
var topValues = [...values].sort((a,b) => b-a).slice(0,5); 
// [...values] will create shallow copy
console.log(topValues); // [789, 689, 98, 65, 33]
```

Answer (score 2):

"number of code lines" efficient code already mentioned in other answers, here is algorithm for better runtime and memory efficiency:

If you can modify input array in place: partition it recursively until your pivot is exactly at 5th position. This approach has linear time average complexity.

Another approach (does not requires modification of input array):

Use max heap tree, iterate over all elements in the input array, on every step insert element into heap tree and remove smallest element from heap if it contains more than 5 elements. This algorithm has N*log(5) running time so again, linear compared to the input array size

Answer (score 2):

The question is ambiguous unless one assumes that the array has no duplicate elements.

```js
// Case 1: unique values
values = [1, 65, 8, 98, 689, 12, 33, 2, 3, 789];
var topValues = [...values].sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0, 5);

console.log(topValues);
// [789, 689, 98, 65, 33]

// Case 2: non-unique values
values = [1, 65, 65, 8, 98, 689, 12, 33, 2, 3, 789];
var topValues = [...values].sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0, 5);

console.log(topValues);
// [789, 689, 98, 65, 65]
```

In case of duplicates what are the top values? If you sort the array `[1, 65, 65, 8, 98, 689, 12, 33, 2, 3, 789]` and take the first 5 values you get

```
[789, 689, 98, 65, 65]
```

To get the top 5 *unique* values use a `filter` with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to select out the repeated values before slicing:

```js
values = [1, 65, 65, 8, 98, 689, 12, 33, 2, 3, 789];
var topValues = 
  [...values].sort((a, b) => b - a)
             .filter((v,i,self) => self.indexOf(v) === i)
             .slice(0, 5);

console.log(topValues);
// [789, 689, 98, 65, 33]
```

Alternatively, on browsers supporting ES6 [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
values = [1, 65, 65, 8, 98, 689, 12, 33, 2, 3, 789];
var topValues = 
  [...new Set(values)].sort((a, b) => b - a)  
                      .slice(0, 5);

console.log(topValues);
// [789, 689, 98, 65, 33]
```

Following [the suggestion in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59542578/2314737) I applied `sort` on a copy of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Any algorithm based on sorting first is inefficient:   The sort complexity is O( n * log(n) )... and it should be solved in O( n ).

Here I implement a "pseudo" priority queue (value == priority) that offers the top N elements (in descending order):

```js
const PriorityQueue = (size = 5) => {
  let queue = [];
  let minValue = 0;

  return {
    addValue,
    getTopValues: () => [...queue]
  };

  function addValue(value) {
    if (queue.length === 0) {
      queue.push(value);
      minValue = value;
    }
    else if (queue.length < size || value > minValue)
      for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++)
        if (queue[i] < value) {
          queue.splice(i, 0, value);
          if (queue.length > size) queue.pop();
          minValue = queue[queue.length - 1];
          break;
        }
  }
}


const queue = PriorityQueue(5);

// Generate 5 million values
const randomNumbers = Array.from({ length: 5000000 }, () => Math.random());
// Add values to the queue
randomNumbers.forEach(queue.addValue);
// Get the top5 elements of the queue
console.log(queue.getTopValues());
```

Here a comparison of performance (in my i5 laptop):

```js
const randomNumbers = Array.from({ length: 5000000 }, () => Math.random());

console.log("\nPriority queue:")
const queue = PriorityQueue(5);
measureTime(() => {
  randomNumbers.forEach(queue.addValue);
  console.log("Top 5:", queue.getTopValues());
});

console.log("\nSort and splice");
measureTime(() => {
  const top5 = randomNumbers.sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0,5);
  console.log("Top 5:", top5);
});

function measureTime(f) {
  const start = new Date();
  f();
  console.log(`Time: ${new Date().getTime() - start.getTime()}ms`)
}
```

Results:

```
Priority queue:
Top 5: [
  0.9999997025204934,
  0.9999995889578723,
  0.999999332274609,
  0.9999986942125549,
  0.9999984105919071
]
Time: 103ms

Sort and splice
Top 5: [
  0.9999997025204934,
  0.9999995889578723,
  0.999999332274609,
  0.9999986942125549,
  0.9999984105919071
]
Time: 5267ms
```

If you need to take 5 max elements of an small array (may be 100 items), sort and slice could be acceptable... but never for me.

Build a good algorithm and encapsulate it in a "getMaxItems(array, n)" function.