# Filter Top X from Array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, typescript

Let's say we have an Array which contains arrays inside:

```
[
["2000-01-01", "xyz1@gmail.com", 1, 9, 338],
["2000-01-01", "xyz2@yahoo.com", 1, 2, 159],
["2000-01-01", "xyz3@yahoo.com", 1, 5, 462],
["2000-01-01", "xyz4@yahoo.com", 1, 6, 417],
["2000-01-01", "xyz5@gmail.com", 1, 3, 156],
["2000-01-01", "xyz6@gmail.com", 1, 8, 414],
]
```

I want to get top 2 based on the last column i.e.

```
["2000-01-01", "xyz3@yahoo.com", 1, 8, 462],
["2000-01-01", "xyz4@yahoo.com", 1, 6, 417],
```

We can use `Array.filter` but not really sure how to in this situation.

Comment: is `x` dynamic?

Comment: Nope, lets say top 3.

Comment: `var top2 = arr.sort((a, b) => b[4] - a[4]).slice(0, 2);`.

Comment: Any `x`: `var top2 = arr.sort((a, b) => b[4] - a[4]).slice(0, x);`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: rather than posting code in comments to answer the question, why not post an answer? It's easier to format, easier to read and leads to the OP being able to accept an answer that you've basically written already.

Comment: @DavidThomas I think this is a rare case where you are right. On most cases, the question is either heavely downvoted or closed by now (due to the lack of attempts). I prefer not to answer those questions, specially if a comment is sufficient.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254218/js-get-top-5-max-elemenets-from-array

Comment: Given the question asked in that proposed duplicate, I'd rather close that one as a dupe of this one; since this one at least has some code in the question; although it'd be much better if the OP had shown some effort or attempts.

Answer (score 4):

You could sort descending by the element at index `4` and take the first two elements.

This propposal features a [destructuring <strike>assignment</strike>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), where an array is taken for destructuring and the property `4` is taken and renamed to `a` rsp. to `b`.

> Example:
>
> ```
>                                                   vvv
> { 4: a } = ["2000-01-01", "xyz1@gmail.com", 1, 9, 338]
>   ^
> ```
>
> Result
>
> ```
> a = 338
> ```

```js
var array = [["2000-01-01", "xyz1@gmail.com", 1, 9, 338], ["2000-01-01", "xyz2@yahoo.com", 1, 2, 159], ["2000-01-01", "xyz3@yahoo.com", 1, 5, 462], ["2000-01-01", "xyz4@yahoo.com", 1, 6, 417], ["2000-01-01", "xyz5@gmail.com", 1, 3, 156], ["2000-01-01", "xyz6@gmail.com", 1, 8, 414]],
    top2 = array.sort(({ 4: a }, { 4: b }) => b - a).slice(0, 2);

console.log(top2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why do we have to do `({ 4: a }, { 4: b }) => b - a`, cant we just do something like `({ 4: a }) => a` ?

Comment: @user3242013 Because `Array#sort` does the sorting by comparing **two** elements at a time.

Comment: you have two parameters to destruct.

Comment: Please explain the code so that others can learn what this answer does, and how the posted solution might apply to other situations in future (this is partially self-interest, since I realise you're destructuring but I'm still a little lost).

Comment: @DavidThomas Me too! JS is evolving quickly. Wow! I'm surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting:

```
 function getTopTwo(array){
    let first = {4: - Infinity}, second = { 4: - Infinity};
    for(const el of array){
      if(el[4] > first[4]){
        second = first;
        first = el;
      } else if(el[4] > second[4]){
       second = el;
      }
    }
    return [first, second];
 }
```

Comment: What about [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48310495/filter-top-x-from-array-of-arrays#comment83606768_48310495)? I think _"Top X"_ is dynamic.

Comment: @ibrahim right, however i think the question is a bit misleading

Comment: By the way, your code is not working. `5 > undefined === false`, `5 < undefined === false` too. So your code always return two empty arrays.